# DS-160 - about other family members traveling with me

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas, spouses

I am filling the DS160 form for a J1 VISA. I am leaving in October for the States while my wife and my children should join me in November. When being asked if "Are there other persons traveling with you?", should I answer yes or no?